# Installing Node.JS on Centos 5.5

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, centos, centos5

I'm trying to install Node.js on Centos 5.5, which the latest update has removed yum.

So when i'm trying to run make I get the following error. Any ideas why, or what is going on?

```
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/node-v0.12.0/out'
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/src/node-v0.12.0/out/Release/lib.host:/usr/local/src/node-v0.12.0/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../deps/v8/tools/gyp; mkdir -p /usr/local/src/node-v0.12.0/out/Release/obj/gen; python ../../tools/js2c.py "/usr/local/src/node-v0.12.0/out/Release/obj/gen/libraries.cc" CORE off ../../src/runtime.js ../../src/v8natives.js ../../src/symbol.js ../../src/array.js ../../src/string.js ../../src/uri.js ../../third_party/fdlibm/fdlibm.js ../../src/math.js ../../src/messages.js ../../src/apinatives.js ../../src/debug-debugger.js ../../src/mirror-debugger.js ../../src/liveedit-debugger.js ../../src/date.js ../../src/json.js ../../src/regexp.js ../../src/arraybuffer.js ../../src/typedarray.js ../../src/weak_collection.js ../../src/promise.js ../../src/object-observe.js ../../src/collection.js ../../src/collection-iterator.js ../../src/macros.py ../../src/array-iterator.js ../../src/string-iterator.js
  File "../../tools/js2c.py", line 409
    except Error as e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make[1]: *** [/usr/local/src/node-v0.12.0/out/Release/obj/gen/libraries.cc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/node-v0.12.0/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

Comment: Looks like a Python version dependency.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy anything you can link for me to have a look at? Would using Pip to make sure Python is the current version be best?

Comment: According to [this page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation#building-prerequisites) (which appears to be at least close to up-to-date), building Node requires Python 2.6 or 2.7. You can type `python --version` to see what you've got currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm encountering the same issue on RHEL5. I found a work-around until this gets fixed upstream. Edit deps/v8/tools/gyp/v8.gyp and replace 'python' with 'python2.7' to force that stage of the compile to use the correct version of python.

I filed an upstream bug at https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/9217

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post "me too" as an answer, even if you can't comment yet. Instead, you may star this question as a favorite to be notified of any new answers. Once you have sufficient reputation, [you may also upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) it.

Comment: You got in before my edit of the solution, work-around @NathanTuggy